# Creating calendar alerts automatically for external users

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, calendar, alert, external-users

We have set up a *Sharepoint online* site for a customer using their Office365 subscription, which has about 10 different subsites.

Employees are licensed and have user accounts via their Office365 identities. They also need to be given administrative access to the Sharepoint site. So far so good.

Some of the subsites needs to be shared with *external users*. Each of these subsites has a Calendar in which meetings, deadlines and other events will be posted.

The customer has asked if we can set up calendar alerts for the external users automatically. So that the calendar alert is set up when we share the site / invite the user.

The reason for this is to:

1. make sure alerts are correctly set up for all users so they are notified of new and/or changed events (in an attempt to make them use this functionality so that events can be simply posted on Sharepoint in the future without having to seperately notify users)
2. not burden the user with having to configure alert settings themselves

So, in summary, having shared the (sub)site with an external user john_doe@outlook.com can we somehow automatically configure alerts for the (sub)sites calendar without having access to Johns Live ID?